# audio unit undeclared indentifier

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio

Im trying to use code from these 2 links (pretty much the same [LINK1](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/) [LINK2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH4-SW1)).  But neither work even with the second link being an apple prog guide.

Like I said the actual error is "use of undeclared identifier" on many of the data types.  To keep this a little shorter I will just show the top 2 data types.

```
 AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;
 AudioComponentDescription desc;
```

From the searching I have done these should be [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) which says they are in the AudioUnit framework.  AudioUnit.framework is added to my "link binarys with libraries" so I dont understand why these data types are not found.

Comment: I have tried <Audiounit.h>, <audiounit.audiounit.h> and with "" instead of <> but no luck.  Other frameworks I have used I have not had to do this. So I'm not sure if its really needed.

Comment: #import <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>

Comment: you can put it in your .pch file to include it everywhere or just in one particular .h or .m, but it is needed

Comment: thank you @hooleyhoop i knew it was something stupid.  Put that as the answer below and ill mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments above i was not importing the header.  I needed to add

```
#import <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>
```