# Using an Audio Queue / Buffer - Objective C

Tags: ios, audio, queue, buffer, audioqueue

I'm currently new to IOS and objective C programming and struggling to understand how to use the audio queue / audio buffer. However I do understand that I should be using the Audio Toolbox framework.

I was wondering if anyone could explain or show me (in it's simplest form) how to load an audio file into a buffer and then play it out?

I currently developing an app as part of university course that streams audio over UDP. I've currently got simple string(text) messages sending between my iPhone and computer but need a way to divide audio into packets. And loading audio into a buffer seems like a good starting point.

Cheers

Comment: Try Novocaine library. It incapsulates painful things while still allowing to access audio at low level. (see examples)

Comment: here is example on another answer here:

example of using audio queue services - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326665/example-of-using-audio-queue-services

Comment: make sure your file format is linear SCM

Comment: And another question/answer.  This one is a complete ogg vorbis player.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863811/how-to-use-audioqueue-to-play-a-sound-for-mac-osx-in-c/30756734#30756734